# passing data with state is undefined

Tags: angular, routes

I have a component that uses router to navigate to another component with a boolean variable like this

```
    isFirstPage: boolean;
    this.router.navigate(['/consume/course/' + this.id, {state: { isFirst: isFirstPage }} ], { replaceUrl: true });
```

in the other component I am trying to get this variable from the router like this

```
 const isFirst = this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state.isFirst;
```

but I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'extras' of null

Why do I have null for the current navigation?

I have also tried https://netbasal.com/set-state-object-when-navigating-in-angular-7-2-b87c5b977bb

```
    this.activatedRoute.paramMap
   .pipe(map(() => window.history.state))
   .subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
   });
```

and

```
this.router.events.pipe(
  filter(e => e instanceof NavigationStart),
  map(() => this.router.getCurrentNavigation().extras.state)
).subscribe(res => {
       console.log(res);
});
```

and I still get undefined

Comment:  you just have a small problem with navigate method check my answer how you can solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

navigate take just two parameters and it base of [NavigationExtras](https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras) interface
and you pass the sate to  commands array that why it **undefined**

```js
  this.router.navigate(['/consume/course/' + this.id], { 
       state: { isFirst: isFirstPage },
       replaceUrl: true 
     });
```

check this [**demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-route-share-object?file=table-basic/table-basic-example.ts)